# Why Kafka emit can not work in try -catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, try-catch, nestjs

I am trying to emit a message to a kafka topic in the catch function, but the code is not work.
here is my code:

```
 constructor(@Inject('any') private readonly kfk: ClientKafka,private prisma: PrismaService,) {}
async Send(){
   try {
      await this.prisma.me.create({
        data: {
          Message:"test",
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
       await this.kfk.emit('Notification.back', {
        Me:"test",
      })
    }
}
```

The Message is string type. When I try to send a non-string Message to the database, it will have an error, and it should execute the code in the catch. However, this.kfk.emit is not working.

Please help

Comment: Doesn't `emit` use `Observables`, so `await` is useless?

Comment: Hi, if I remove await, still not work

Comment: It's still an observable. Do you know how Observables work to begin with and how they differ from promises?

Comment: no.. I am new to nestjs..

Comment: Observables aren't a NestJS concept. [They're their own thing entirely](https://rxjs.dev) Nest just makes use of them for microservices and websockets

Comment: Thank you!  can you give me some advice about solving my problem?

Comment: Do you expect this `send` method to return anything?